# FFMPEG Metadata Extraction Fails

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, extract

I have a little issue with FFMPEG on Windows:

*ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www_gyan_dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers*

I Have got a video and a zip file to embed in the container as metadata
I encoded source files with the command

```
.\ffmpeg.exe  -y  -i D:\TestVideo3_T0.mkv -map 0 -attach .\TestVideo3_Merged_Meta.zip -metadata:s:t mimetype=application/zip -c:v copy D:\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv
```

Result of encoded data:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'D:\TestVideo3_T0.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4461 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Rext), gbrp(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 2048x1536, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
      DURATION        : 00:00:02.000000000
Output #0, matroska, to 'D:\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Rext), gbrp(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 2048x1536, q=2-31, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
      DURATION        : 00:00:02.000000000
  Stream #0:1: Attachment: none
    Metadata:
      filename        : .\TestVideo3_Merged_Meta.zip
      mimetype        : application/zip
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  File .\TestVideo3_Merged_Meta.zip -> Stream #0:1
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   20 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3473kB time=00:00:01.70 bitrate=16727.1kbits/s speed= 554x
video:1086kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 219.801529%
```

When I analyze the output file I can find the zip file embedded on the mkv video.
Deconding the file seems not working. (I tries -dump_attacment:s :s:t :t, ecc...)

```
.\ffmpeg -y -i .\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv -dump_attachment:t .\Meta.zip

ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www_gyan_dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
[matroska,webm @ 0000023ddd5cf880] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Attachment: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '.\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14226 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Rext), gbrp(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 2048x1536, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
      DURATION        : 00:00:02.000000000
  Stream #0:1: Attachment: none
    Metadata:
      filename        : .\TestVideo3_Merged_Meta.zip
      mimetype        : application/zip
At least one output file must be specified
PS D:\> .\ffmpeg -y -i .\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv -dump_attachment:s:t .\Meta.zip
ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
[matroska,webm @ 000002492afef7c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Attachment: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '.\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14226 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Rext), gbrp(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 2048x1536, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
      DURATION        : 00:00:02.000000000
  Stream #0:1: Attachment: none
    Metadata:
      filename        : .\TestVideo3_Merged_Meta.zip
      mimetype        : application/zip
At least one output file must be specified
```

Can anyone give a hint to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`-dump_attachment` goes before the input with the attachment.

```
ffmpeg -y -dump_attachment:t .\Meta.zip -i .\TestVideo3_Merged.mkv
```